# Can I buy Travel Answers goodies?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I want to have a:

- Sticker with the logo of Travel.se for my laptop
- a t-shirt stating: "This journey has been made possible by http://travel.stackexchange.com"
- a bumper sticker
- [UK blocking stickers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/981/whats-the-name-for-the-blocking-stickers-used-on-car-headlights), with travel.se logo.

Long question short, is there a goody store and if not is it okay to create one on Cafepress for example??

Comment: If SE were to provide headlight converters it could be useful to have both sets, left to right and right to left.

Comment: I also like to have a sticker for my laptop :-)

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is a no. The SE shop no longer exists, although swag tends to be made available for high rep users or for events.

See [Buy Stack Overflow shirt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143348/154443) - which also indicates that licencing of the trademarks are also disallowed.

Comment: What a pity. From a making-money perspective I can understand the position SE takes. In the context of travel.se, though it is more free publicity. Stackoverflow can draw enough attention using twitter for example. Especially a shirt stating that this journey was made possible by travel.se could attract the much needed attention from the right audience.

Comment: Absolutely! I saw Petra because of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46096/one-way-trip-from-tel-aviv-to-petra-and-more-in-jordan this. It is extremely unlikely I would've gotten there without this thread.